# What's the meaning of the '\\|o+' in `string-split' function?

Tags: regex, elisp

What's the meaning of the `\\|o+` usage in the following elisp code? Why it is different from the first example?

```
(split-string "ooo" "o+" nil)
;; ("" "")

(split-string "ooo" "\\|o+" nil)
;; ("" "o" "o" "o" "")
```

Answer (score 2):

`"\\|"` specifies an alternative between the expressions on either side, so the regexp `"\\|o+"` matches either an empty string, or one-or-more "o"s.

In your first example you've returned the two empty strings separated by the three "o"s.

In the second example the empty string separator matches at every character in the input, so each character is returned separately.